# Detecting an OnFormClosing event from a child form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, formclosing

I have a parent form, called form A. This creates child form, lets say called form B.

For A subscribes to form B's FormClosing event and makes changes based on this action.

What I want to know is, how do I detect which control in Form B caused the FormClosing event to trigger. I want the code to behave one way if the "X" or "Cancel" buttons are pressed and another if the OK button is pressed.

The code looks like this:

```
Private Sub btnAddSections_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddSections.Click
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Dim frm As New dlgAddPartsMartixSection(m_intMatrixId)
    AddHandler frm.FormClosing, AddressOf btnAddSectionsRefresh
    frm.Show()
    Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub 

 Private Sub btnAddSectionsRefresh(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs)
    dgvParts.DataSource = Nothing
    btnAddParts.Enabled = False
    dgvParts.Refresh()
    Me.LoadPartMatrices()
    dgvMatrices.Rows(m_intMatrixLocationId).Selected = True
    Me.LoadPartSections(m_intMatrixId)
End Sub
```

Any ideas/Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the arguments to the method tell you everything. Investigate on

```
Private Sub btnAddSectionsRefresh(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs)
```

and you should be able to determine who caused this by checking out the `sender` parameter.

Comment: The problem I have with that is the object it's passing back as sender is the entire form. I am fairly certain I am doing something wrong......

Comment: You must be calling methods when you either press `Cancel` or `OK`, are you? So if these have `Click`-events, you could set an object to a certain state for either `Cancel` or `OK` and if you click on `X` it might be `null` or anything, so you know it was NOT `OK`. How about this? You can then read the state in the `Closing`-method?

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx) property to determine how form B was closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
     Private Sub btnAddSectionsRefresh(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs)
           if  Me.ActiveControl.Text = "X" then
.....
......
elseif Me.ActiveControl.Text="Cancel"
.....
.....
elseif Me.ActiveControl.Text ="Ok"
.....
...
        End Sub
```